# How to debug react-admin graphql redux application

Tags: redux, graphql, react-admin

I'm using `react-admin` with `ra-data-graphql` as my data provider but with a custom buildQuery to match my `postgraphile` server's graphql flavor.

After invoking GET_LIST for one of my resources I get the following error:

`Warning: Missing translation for key: "Illegal invocation"`

I tried to log the actions using a custom reducer. I can see that a failure action is being dispacthed but I can't see where and why...

How can I debug the application to better understand it?

Sadly I can't share the code right now, many thanks!

Edit:
In my case the error was thrown because I was missing an `id` field in  my response.

Comment: Just interested, did you get postgraphile working with react-admin?

Comment: Yes I did, I had to reimplement the graphql query builder part to match syntax. Might publish this as a package in the future.

Comment: You can chime in here: https://twitter.com/jiv_e/status/1120550835195383808

Comment: @jiv-e I don't have a twitter account but I'll send you a gist soon.

Comment: @jiv-e Check out the gist I just posted: gist.github.com/ak-il/e91bfbd2c7c83086c7ded41512335795
I didn't check for errors yet in this gist but it should work with the latest version of postgraphile and react-admin as of publishing it

Comment: Great! Thanks, @ak-il!